# Running include_tasks via Python API

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm currently trying to turn a set of action calls into a single reusable action. I realized that "include_tasks" is not a module, so it can't be executed using `self._execute_module()`.

Is there a way to use the "include_tasks" action from Ansible directly in Python?

Ansible: 2.10.3, Python: 3.8.5

Comment: Are you familiar with the [`ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/reference_appendices/config.html#default-debug) environment variable, and the [exercising your module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html#exercising-module-code-locally) page in the fine manual?

Comment: So far I've been using the verbose flag when running the playbook to get more output.  I'll try the other way you mentioned for debugging.

Comment: I've realized that I it does not work as "include_tasks" is not a module. I rephrased my question.